# how to save and retrive my images from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php with mysql.

I want to create a form with different fields.

The form in html is looking like this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var categories = [];
categories["startList"] = ["Rental","Sale"]
categories["Rental"] = ["Residential","Commercial"];
categories["Sale"] = ["Commercial","Residential"];
categories["Residential"] = ["Flot","Independent"];
categories["Commercial"] = ["Play & Plug","Baseshare"];
categories["Biography"] = ["Play & Plug","Bareshare"];
categories["Fiction"] = ["Flot","Independent"];
var nLists = 3; // number of select lists in the set

function fillSelect(currCat,currList){
var step = Number(currList.name.replace(/\D/g,""));
for (i=step; i<nLists+1; i++) {
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].length = 1;
document.forms['tripleplay']['List'+i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
var nCat = categories[currCat];
for (each in nCat) {
var nOption = document.createElement('option'); 
var nData = document.createTextNode(nCat[each]); 
nOption.setAttribute('value',nCat[each]); 
nOption.appendChild(nData); 
currList.appendChild(nOption); 
} 
}



function init() {
 fillSelect('startList',document.forms['tripleplay']['List1'])
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init,     false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);
function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
  if (document.getElementById){
    var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
    for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2];     val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
      if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
        if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
          if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail     address.\n';
        } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
          if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
          if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
            min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
            if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between     '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
      } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
     } if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
    document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
} }
</script> 

</head>
 <body>

    <table width="60%"><form action="process.php" method="post"     enctype="multipart/form-data" name="tripleplay"     onsubmit="MM_validateForm('fullname','','R','area','','R','ownermobile','','RisNum','email'    ,'','RisEmail','otherdetail','','R');return document.MM_returnValue">
       <tr>
    <td width="44%">Full Name : </td>
    <td width="56%"><input size="25" type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Rental Type:</td>


    <td>

    <select name='List1' id="List1"     onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
<option selected>Make a Selection</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select name='List2' id="List2" onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List3'])">
  <option selected>Make a Selection</option>
</select><br /><br />
<select name='List3' id="List3" onchange="getValue(this.value,     this.form['List2'].value, 
this.form['List1'].value)">
  <option selected>Make a Selection</option>
</select>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Area : </td>
    <td><input size="25" type="text" name="area" id="area" />
      sq.ft.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Owner Mobile / Landline</td>
    <td><input size="25" type="text" name="ownermobile" id="ownermobile" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p>E-mail</p></td>
    <td><input size="25" type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Pictures of Property</td>
    <td>

      <input type="file" name="image_one" id="image_one" />


        <input type="file" name="image_two" id="image_two" />


        <input type="file" name="image_three" id="image_three" />
    </td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Other details you would like to share about your property:</td>
     <td><textarea size="25" name="otherdetail" id="otherdetail" cols="45" rows="5">    </textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

AND MY form processing file is looking like this.

```
<?
if( $_POST )
{
  $con =     mysql_connect("","","");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("vkrental", $con);

  $users_fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
  $users_area = $_POST['area'];
  $users_List1 = $_POST['List1'];
  $users_List2 = $_POST['List2'];
  $users_List3 = $_POST['List3'];
  $users_ownermobile = $_POST['ownermobile'];
  $users_email = $_POST['email'];
  $users_image_one = $_POST['image_one'];
  $users_image_two = $_POST['image_two'];
  $users_image_three = $_POST['image_three'];
  $users_otherdetail = $_POST['otherdetail'];


  $users_fullname = htmlspecialchars($users_fullname);
  $users_area = htmlspecialchars($users_area);
  $users_List1 = htmlspecialchars($users_List1);
  $users_List2 = htmlspecialchars($users_List2);
  $users_List3 = htmlspecialchars($users_List3);

  $users_ownermobile = htmlspecialchars($users_ownermobile);
  $users_email = htmlspecialchars($users_email);
  $users_image_one = htmlspecialchars($users_image_one);
  $users_image_two = htmlspecialchars($users_image_two);
  $users_image_three = htmlspecialchars($users_image_three);
  $users_otherdetail = htmlspecialchars($users_otherdetail);




  $query = "
   INSERT INTO `vkrental`.`Owner_detail` (

`fullname` ,
`area` ,
`List1` ,
`List2` ,
`List3` ,

 `ownermobile` ,
`email` ,
`image_one` ,
`image_two` ,
`image_three` ,
`otherdetail`
)
VALUES ( '$users_fullname',
    '$users_area', '$users_List1','$users_List2','$users_List3', '$users_ownermobile', '$users_email', '$users_image_one','$users_image_two','$users_image_three', '$users_otherdetail'
        );";

  mysql_query($query);

  echo "<h2>.</h2>";

  mysql_close($con);
}
 ?>
```

and mysql table is looking like this

```
CREATE TABLE `Owner_detail` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `fullname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `List1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `List2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `List3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ownermobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `image_one` blob NOT NULL,
  `image_two` blob NOT NULL,
   `image_three` blob NOT NULL,
  `otherdetail` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;
```

My Problem is 
1) on mysql table the image show's [BLOB - 0 B], but i need to show this image on phpmyadmin as well as my web browser?
2) on my phpmyadmin(localhost) is show's an underline whenever my cursor is going on, but not in my web host. why this ?

any help is great full.

Comment: `$users_image_one = htmlspecialchars($users_image_one);`?

Comment: It's really bad idea to store image in database. You have to store the image in filesystem and store its name in database.

Comment: you will have to modify your phpmyadmin to show the image, because `blob` doesn't always mean image, it means a binary object. So it can be anything.

Comment: Why you have to store image in binary object? Save the image path into database will be fine.

Comment: Why would you retrieve input and then clean it in two steps? it's possible in one, and still readable

    $users_fullname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fullname']);

Comment: @AaaronJiang when the user enter their image and click on submit button then how to save that image path into mydql database using below code. please help me.